# Концы стрелок перекрываются узлами графа

Tags: python, графы, matplotlib, рисование, networkx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую `NetworkX` для рисования графов на Python. Почему стрелки указывают не на границу узла? Как это исправить?

```
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
print(pos)
node_sizes = [len(key)*430 for key in pos]
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'),
                       node_color='W', edgecolors='BLACK', 
                       node_shape='o', node_size=node_sizes)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edge_color='r', arrows=True, arrowsize=80)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, arrows=False)
```

Comment: можете привести код для построения графа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()

G.add_edges_from([
  ('t1', 'c1'),
  ('t1', 'c2'),
  ('c1', 'c2'),
  ('c2', 'c1'),
  ('p2', 'c1'),
  ('c2', 'p2')
])

attrs = {'c1':{'key':100},
         'c2':{'key':50},
         't1':{'key':15},
         'p2':{'key':30}}
nx.set_node_attributes(G, attrs)

node_sizes = [a['key']*30 for n,a in G.nodes(data=True)]

# drawing ...    
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True,
        cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'),
        node_size=node_sizes,
        arrows=True, arrowsize=40)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!